# How to use dplyr as alternative to aggregate

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe `times` that looks like this:

```
user     time
A        7/7/2010
B        7/12/2010
C        7/12/2010
A        7/12/2010 
C        7/15/2010
```

I'm using `aggregate(time ~ user, times, function(x) sort(as.vector(x)))` to get this:

```
user     time
A        c(7/7/2010, 7/12/2010)
B        c(7/12/2010)
C        c(7/12/2010, 7/15/2010)
```

The problem is that I have over 20 million entries in `times` so `aggregate` is taking a over 4 hours. Is there any alternative using `dplyr` that will get me the sorted vector of dates?

Comment: This is pretty trivial with `data.table`, e.g. `setDT(times)[,.(time = list(sort(time))), by = "user"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:** Based on your comment, how about this:

```
library(dplyr)

# Data (with a few additions)
times = read.table(text="user     time
A        7/7/2010
B        7/12/2010
B 7/13/2010
C        7/12/2010
A        7/12/2010 
A 7/13/2010
C        7/15/2010", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

times$time = as.Date(times$time, "%m/%d/%Y")

times
```

> ```
>   user       time
> 1    A 2010-07-07
> 2    B 2010-07-12
> 3    B 2010-07-13
> 4    C 2010-07-12
> 5    A 2010-07-12
> 6    A 2010-07-13
> 7    C 2010-07-15
> ```

```
times %>% group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(First=min(time),
            Last=max(time),
            N = n(),
            minDiff=min(diff(time)),
            meanDiff=mean(diff(time)),
            NumDiffUniq = length(unique(diff(time))))
```

> ```
>    user      First       Last     N        minDiff       meanDiff NumDiffUniq
> 1     A 2010-07-07 2010-07-13     3         1 days         3 days           2
> 2     B 2010-07-12 2010-07-13     2         1 days         1 days           1
> 3     C 2010-07-12 2010-07-15     2         3 days         3 days           1
> ```

**Original Answer:**

I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. If you just want your data frame to be sorted, then with `dplyr` you would do:

```
library(dplyr)

times.sorted = times %>% arrange(user, time)
```

If you want `time` to become a string of dates for each `user`, then you could do:

```
times.summary = times %>% group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(time = paste(time, collapse=","))
```

But note that for each user this will result in a single string containing the dates.

```
times.summary
```

> ```
>    user                time
> 1     A  7/7/2010,7/12/2010
> 2     B           7/12/2010
> 3     C 7/12/2010,7/15/2010
> ```

If you actually want each cell to be a vector of dates, you could make each cell a list (though there might be a better way). For example:

```
times.new = times %>% group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(time = list(as.vector(time)))

times.new$time
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "7/7/2010"  "7/12/2010"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "7/12/2010"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "7/12/2010" "7/15/2010"
> ```

But if your goal is to analyze your data by group, then you don't actually need to do any of the above. You can use base, `dplyr`, or `data.table` functions to perform any analysis by group without first sorting your data.

Comment: thank you, this is very useful. I should have been more clear as to what I want to accomplish. At the end I would like to have a dataset with the following variables:
user | first time | last time | total times | min difference between times | average difference between times | are all diff between times the same (True / False)

I managed to create something like this on a smaller sample using aggregate. But with 20M users aggregate takes over 4 hours.

Comment: The updated answer is much faster than my original code using `aggregate`. The challenge is still runtime. The code in the updated answer took just under a minute to run on  1000 entries on a computer with 128G of RAM. I could be looking at a couple of weeks of runtime if I don't find a more efficient solution. I believe I may need to reformulate this query in sql.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it took that long with just 1,000 rows. I would have thought that would take a fraction of a second. In any case, `data.table` would almost certainly be faster. If no one adds a `data.table` answer tonight, I'll see if I can cook one up tomorrow.

Comment: thank you @eipi10 . I managed to chunk the task in such a way as to reduce the runtime. However, when sending the jobs to my unis servers I got the following error "This is R 3.0.2, package 'dplyr' needs >= 3.1.2", I may actually need to figure out a `data.table` solution. If you have any thoughts on the matter I'd really appreaciate them.

Comment: It looks like the Unix server you're shipping the job out to has an older version of R (latest is 3.3.1) that is incompatible with the version of dplyr you're trying to use. I'm not sure what the "typical" approach is in these situations. Can you get the Unix admin to install the latest version of R? Alternatively, can you install an earlier version of dplyr (see the [old sources](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/) page for previous versions of dplyr)?

Comment: I was on the interview in world biggest retail company and got a laptop with R 2.14 in it (it was this year), surprisingly `data.table` works fine, some oldish `1.8.x` but still way better than base R. It is hard to precisely define what R is an *old* enough to not care about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `dplyr` solution by **eipi10**  and the suggestion of **nrussell**, I've written the following solution using `data.table`.

First you need to format the variable `times`:

```
times$time = as.Date(times$time, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Then you'll need to convert `times` to a data.table using:

```
library(data.table)
times <- as.data.table(times)
```

Overwriting `times` was useful for my purposes but you may want to instantiate a new variable.  After formatting your dataframe as a data.table just do:

```
new.times <- times[, 
                    .(first = min(time),
                      last = max(time),
                      n = .N,
                      meandiff = mean(diff(time)),
                      mindiff = min(diff(time)),
                      numdiffuniq = length(unique(diff(time))),
                      by='user')]
```

Running on a linux virtual machine with 128G RAM and using a sample of 1000 entires, the elapsed runtime was 0.43s.

See [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-table-r-tutorial#gs.LSAXRu0) for more on data.table.